# adding javascript into html files

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements, noscript

I am attempting to add a simple condition into an html file as a test.  I am trying to create a simple file that tells the user wether his javascript is enabled or not.

```
    <Noscript>
        <A>Javascript is disabled</a>
    </noscript>

    <Script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        <A>Javascript is enabled</a>
    </script>
```

When I run the script, I get a syntax error.  If I change the type to javascript, the error goes away but the code does not work.   Why do I get this error and can anyone suggest a good javascript editing tool because I'm using notepad to learn.

Comment: Friend, you are supposed to insert javascript code inside the script block and not HTML.

Comment: A script wrapper expects JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: Inside the script tag: `document.write('<a>Javascript is enabled</a>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print in javascript you use `document.write('...');`

Here is a good site where you can learn Javascript -> http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Answer (score 0):

The noscript tag will do the trick for users without JavaScript enabled. For those that have it enabled use JavaScript to display the enabled text.

```
<noscript>
JavaScript is not available
</noscript>

<p id="enabled">
</p>

<script>
var enabledTag = document.getElementById("enabled").innerHTML = "Javascript is enabled";
enabledTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Javascript is enabled"));
</script>
```

[Try it on jsFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/vcDkC/)